# trying to get the value of item where the sortable item is placed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code where i need to do the sorting and it works fine till the sorable as i get what i want, what i missing is the information where the element is taking the place of other element, i need the information of the other element because that element is placed with old moved item's location: My code below works one way but i want to get the values of both the moved and movable values:

```
$('tbody').sortable({
                    items: siblingRow,
                    axis: "y",
                    containment: "parent",
                    helper: sortableHelper,
                    connectWith: "tr.childrow",
                    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
                    start: function(e, ui) {
                        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper[0].scrollHeight);
                        ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
                    },
                    receive: function(e, ui) {
                        console.log(ui);
                        //return true;
                    },
                    stop: function(e,ui) {
                        console.log(ui);
                    },
                    update: function (e, ui) {
                        var startPos = ui.item.startPos;
                        var endPos = ui.item.index();
                        console.log(startPos);
                    console.logendPos);
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: no one knows the answer to this question?

Comment: I think the issue is that it's hard to understand what you're asking in this question. Look at http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update and review the `position` and the `originalPosition`

Comment: i solved this by using `ui.item.previousSibling`